# Google map won't embed on it's own

Tags: google-maps

This is very strange.

I'm trying to embed a google map on a site, but, it won't show correctly unless I include another map above it.

To clarify, the map I'm trying to include is one of the UK, when I add that on it's own I get a map of the US.

This is what I'm having to do which is pretty nasty:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

<iframe width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?oe=utf-8&amp;ll=53.911492,-1.313405&amp;spn=0.081801,0.264187&amp;t=m&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

The second map is the one I want but if I delete the map above it, it fails to work.

Is there an obvious reason for this I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

This seems to only be a Firefox issue, which makes it even stranger to me.

Comment: No issue for me: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9Fg2p/

Comment: Does it happen in a particular browser?

Comment: The first `iframe` should be UK? Because it is an address in the USA.

Comment: Must not have anything to do with what you have posted.  Works for me in firefox.